# Why FloatVectorProperty of subtype 'QUATERNION' is of type EULER?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties, quaternion

The `FloatVectorProperty` gets `subtype` argument to change the data type of float vector. After setting this argument to subtype `QUATERNION`, it just holds an Euler type not `Quaternion`.

how can I change this to hold a quaternion value?

Answer (score 1):

Quaternion data-types need 4 float values while euler rotation data-types need only 3 values and the default size for `FloatVectorProperty` is 3 ; so together with `subtype` argument that should be set to `QUATERNION` we should also set the `size` argument to 4 and the field now holds a quaternion data-type.